# How can I add/append content to the_content on the home page via a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development

As a proof of concept, I'd like to create a simple plugin that loads some content, say "hello world" just after the_content on the home page only. How can I do this from a plugin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean a filter and a check for `is_home()`?

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse6034_the_content' );
function wpse6034_the_content( $content )
{
    if ( is_home() ) {
        $content .= '<p>Hello World!</p>';
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Jan, can you tell me how you might alter your example, if I only want my plugin to filter content when the home page is viewed? This example works, but it runs the filter on every page.

Comment: @Scott: Then you want to run `add_filter()` only when `is_home()` is true. Remember that you can't check for `is_home()` only after the query has run, so probably in the `init` hook?

Comment: Any idea if I want to do something similar? Simple plug-in that creates `new custom` home page. Nothing comes from active theme. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110118/how-to-create-custom-home-page-via-plugin

Comment: Perhaps useful to the next guy, it took me awhile to realize you don't want to `$content = get_the_content()` and then append to that (which is not what this example shows either). Doing so will mess things like auto-embeds up.