# How to create custom home page via plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, customization, page-template, frontpage

I want to code a plug-in that creates new custom home page. Note that I have never coded any plug-in before.

1) After activation of plug-in user needs to go to the options of the plug-in and set up that current home page will be replaced by the one that this plug-in generates ( I hope I can code this bit somehow in the future )

2) **Plug-in generates custom home page that displays only**

- title and body of the latest post
- number of comments

Could someone help me how to code the **2)** ?

Currently I have one php file that is very simple plug-in. I can activate / deactivate it but I don't know how to code the home page.

I'll be using WP 3.6

Answer (score 1):

#### An Active Plugin

To make an active plugin, use the following resources:

> - [WordPress Codex: Writing a Plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin)
> - [WordPress Essentials: How To Create A WordPress Plugin](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/30/how-to-create-a-wordpress-plugin/) by [Daniel Pataki](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/author/daniel-pataki/?rel=author)

From the following StackExchange thread, try to understand what are the Hooks and what are things acting behind a plugin:

> - [How to edit a wordpress plugin without break its update process](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30405/how-to-edit-a-wordpress-plugin-without-break-its-update-process) - WordPress Answers

#### Template Hiearchy

Then you will need to learn the WordPress Template Hierarchy. For WordPress Template hierarchy consult the Codex page for [Template Hierarchy#In Detail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#The_Template_Hierarchy_In_Detail). Get idea about the *Home Page Display* and *Front Page Display* template settings.

#### Custom Home Page

Now try to find out a way to make your own custom home page. Use whether the `front-page.php` or `home.php` template and display your own homepage. Hook to `wp_head()` on the `header.php` to echo your custom codes/ custom template other than the default one. Hook some code to overwrite the `Settings > Reading` rules in WP-Admin.

> REMEMBER: *All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy* - so implement, initiate, and integrate what you've learnt. Don't wait to someone will appear with a bunch of code and you'll paste 'em to make your own. *"cerca trova"* - "Seek and ye shall find". Good luck.

Comment: Great lead! Now my plug-in outputs html before the theme does. But how can I make it so the current theme doesn't output anything?