# Adding something to the_content

Tags: custom-post-types

I want to add some content to every page of a custom content type. The content type is the “encyclopedia” add-on for wordpress.

At the bottom of every page I want to add the References. 
These are input as a custom field when the article is edited. I currently have a sidebar widget that shows the references, but for SEO purposes, and better visibility on the page, I want to add these under an additional header at the end of the article - so it appears as though it is part of the article.

I could do it manually, but I have over 1,000 encyclopedia entries.

I think what i need to do is add a filter, with a check for the custom content type, similar to this:
[How can I add/append content to the_content on the home page via a plugin?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6034/how-can-i-add-append-content-to-the-content-on-the-home-page-via-a-plugin)

But I don’t understand where to put this code, or how to call my custom content type.

In my sidebar widget, the custom content type is called with a shortcode by the acf plugin.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

So far with a bit of googling, I have cobbled something together, but the “is_single” is obviously not right, and I don’t know where to put this code.

```
add_filter ('the_content', 'references’); function references($content) {    if(is_single()) {
      $content.= '<h3>References</h3>';
      $content.= '[acf field="sources"]';
      $content.= '<a href="https://***.com/sources">Read more about our sources</a>';    }    return $content; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You mostly got everything right. But the code you posted also gave an error caused by an `’` char in your code.

```
add_filter ('the_content', 'references'); 
function references( $content ) {    

    // only run the code on singular views of the post type "my_custom_post_type"
    if( is_singular('my_custom_post_type') ) { // insert your custom post type here

        // get current post ID
        $post_id = get_the_ID();

       // get your custom field here using what you need;
       // maybe use: get_post_meta( $post_id, 'custom_field_name');
       // you showed a shortcode, than maybe use:
       // do_shortcode('[acf field="custom_field_name"]');
       $custom_field = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'custom_field_name');

      $content.= '<h3>References</h3>';
      $content.= $custom_field;
      $content.= '<a href="https://***.com/sources">Read more about our sources</a>';    
    }    

    return $content; 
}
```

For example if you replace `my_custom_post_type` with `product` (the WooCommerce post-type) you will only see this content on single product pages.

You should put this code inside your functions.php or better, inside a plugin.